# Plone: Getting sent mail status

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I was reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020128/tracing-postfix-mail-status In fact I have tried-

```
   from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName   
   mailhost = getToolByName(context, 'MailHost') 
   print mailhost.my_mails()
```

I can't manage to read my sent mail status. Is there any way to get sent mail status? I'm thinking about log file. But getting that info with plone would be nice. Thanks for your suggestion in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/misc/email.html? You get immediate feedback if you're unable to send mail.

Comment: thanks @T. Kim Nguyen Is there any folder in server running plone where sent mails are stored like we watch in web mail?

Comment: @user119247 the mailhost in Plone simply connects to the specified SMTP server and synchronously sends the email. If you wanted to store sent emails, you would add a cc or bcc email address, and you could certainly do that with Plone, but Plone itself does not store sent emails. A developer might be able to modify the default mailhost to store a copy of sent emails, or you could possibly create your own mailhost that stores sent email locally and invoke it rather than the default mailhost to send your emails.

Comment: Thanks @ t-kim-nguyen